# Rig Shaaka followers in vadakalai sect of Srivaishnavam & alternatively, see lot of yajur & saama shaaka followers in vaishnavam (vadakalai followers)

Tags: rig-veda

Basis some priliminary search through the search engine to understand more about the correct way of abhivadhaye, understood the following possibilities, in case of Rig veda follwers :

Abhivaadaye... Vaasishta, Maithravaruna, Koundinya
thraiyarusheya pravaraanvita (1)
Koundinya gotraHa (2)
Asvalayana suutraH (3)
Rig shaakha adhyaayii (4)
shrii ....... sharmaa naama ahaM asmibhoH||

But largely atleast on the commonly available platform such as youtube, forums i couldnot find many rig shaaka adhyaayii in srivaishnavam.. but more from smaartha's.. & yajur,saama veda followers in srivaishnavam... Hence wanted to check the correct understanding from here..

Also, wrt sutraah for rig/rg .. asvalyaana & katyanana are there... which one to pronounce incase, i don't have any elders to guide me on this..

Apologies incase, if i have misspelled or misrepresented anything.

Looking forward for some insights through this forum